# Angular 8 refresh values of data bind

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular component which has a boolean variable "BodyToggle". In the component.ts file, I set it to true on a click event, and when the variable is set to true, I have an ngIf condition which triggers a modal.

component.ts

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Output, Input, ViewEncapsulation, Injectable, AfterViewInit, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChange} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-chart1',
    templateUrl: `./chart1.component.html`
    , encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit { 
    BodyToggle: boolean = false;
    getCharts(){

        let currentContext = this;
        if (item.displayType === "bar") {
            ....
            ....
            events: {
                      click: function(){
                         //show modal
                          currentContext.BodyToggle = true;


                      }
            }


    }

}
```

component.html

```
<div id="container">


    <div *ngIf="BodyToggle">
        <clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="BodyToggle" [clrModalSize]="'lg'">
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </clr-modal>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, when I first render the modal, when I trigger the click event, the BodyToggle variable is set to true, but it is not reflected in the view (HTML). When I refresh the page, at the click event, I see the change to the variable BodyToggle reflected in the view. I dont understand why it does not reflect when I render the component for the first time. I also tried to use a setTimeOut to the set the value to true.

```
let currentContext = this;
click: function() {

                              //show modal

                                currentContext.BodyToggle = false;
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                   currentContext.BodyToggle = true;

                                });
```

This also doesnt seem to solve the issue. Using ChangeDetectorRef throws a "provider not found" error, as this component is a child component to another parent component. Could you please help me how to implement this so that when the component is first rendered, a change to the variable BodyToggle should reflect in the view (HTML). (Basically looking for an implementation similar to scope.apply in angular)

EDIT

I did try ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges(), but I was getting a provider not found error.

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ExpandableOompaLoompa -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ExpandableOompaLoompa -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ExpandableOompaLoompa -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ExpandableOompaLoompa -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!
```

This is how I did implemented it in the component.ts file.

```
constructor(private crd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
.....
events: {
                      click: function(){
                         //show modal
                          currentContext.BodyToggle = true;
                          cdr.detectChanges();


                      }
            }
```

I also tried ApplicationRef.tick(), that did not work at all. Could you help me with why this error might have been occuring? Thanks

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the event in your code is out of angular scope. the angular life-cycle does not detects it. 
you should call change detection manually

```
ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
```

take a look at this for more information about manual change detection trigger
[Triggering change detection manually in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-change-detection-manually-in-angular)